# Autoload objects and functions with a single function call

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm working on a script in RStudio which has become pretty large over the past weeks. New features, of course, depend on objects and functions defined in other parts of the script but it's tedious to find the corresponding lines and execute these individually. I would rather write a little function that loads all desired objects (which are stored as .RData) and functions at once. However, if I naively copy-paste the load()-statements and function definitions in a function and execute it, nothing happens.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `envir` argument to `load`. Inside a function, `load` will load into the function's environment, not the global environment. You can either modify the `envir` argument (perhaps to `.GlobalEnv`), or return all the elements from the function as a list and then do with them as you wish.

Comment: The `envir` argument works perfectly but how can I get the functions to the global scope?

Comment: That's what `envir=.GlobalEnv` should do.

Comment: Yes, but it only works when loading objects. I should've mentioned that I also wanted to return user-defined functions that are created within the convenience function. Anyway, I used the `<<-` operator instead of `<-` and now everything is doing well. Thanks.

Comment: You can put those in the `.GlobalEnv` using `assign` (or the `<<-` assignment operator, but `assign` is more explicit whereas `<<-` doesn't necessarily assign into the global environment).

Answer (score 0):

Hi for loading all the RData from a rep you can do like this :

```
r_datas <- list.files( path = "DATA/", full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".*\\.RData" )
invisible( lapply( X = r_datas, FUN = load, envir = .GlobalEnv ) )
```